# Can't install both libmyodbc and iODBC at the same time on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mysql, database

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/adding-an-odbc-driver-for-mysql-on-ubuntu) on Adding an ODBC driver to Ubuntu.

I installed `iODBC` and then I went to install `libmyodbc` and noticed that it uninstalled `iODBC`, and now I can't follow the rest of the tutorial...because either the driver is gone, or the GUI to install the driver is gone.

`iodbcadm-gtk` is part of the `iODBC` package but when `libmyodbc` is installed it removes the *iODBC*, rendering it useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay figured this out.  I ended up installing just `libmyodbc` and configuring odbc using the `/etc/odbc.ini` file:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
odbcname = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN

[the_db]
Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description = The Database using MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER = localhost
PORT =
USER = root
Password = someOldPassword
Database = the_db
OPTION = 3
SOCKET =
```

It works great!